# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/users/register

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created a login and registration web-page under MERN stack and now when I am submitting my form I am getting the error mentioned in the post title.

I am starting up my app using **npm start** and I think I am having this due to Https calling from client or proxy mentioned in my Package.json file.

I have used create-react-app for this project.

I have shared the code below; can anybody suggest some solution to it?

if any other reference of code is needed from my side then do let me know please..

thank you in advance!

I have tried to resolve it by using advance proxy settings of create-react-app but nothing happened

**../client/package.json**

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy":  "http://localhost:5000",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**../package.json**

```
  "name": "login-registration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.2",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.38.0"
  }
}
```

**../server.js**

```
var cors = require ('cors')
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var app = express()
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var Users = require('./routes/users')

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running at port: " + port)
})
```

**../routes/User.js**

```
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

users.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date()
    const userData = {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created: today
    }
    console.log("UserData read");
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
         }
    })
        .then(user => {
            if(!user){
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    userData.password = hash
                    User.create(userData)
                        .then(user => {
                            res.json({status: user.email + ' registered'})
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            res.send('error: ' + err)
                        })
                })  
            }   else {
                res.json({error: "User already exists"})
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error: ' + err)
        })
})

users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user => {
        if(user) {
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                    expiresin: 1440
                })
                res.send(token)
            }
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({error: 'User does not exist'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err})
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

Comment: Is your backend i.e server running ?

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: Shall I share the back-end logs?

Comment: @JawadAli That would be great. I thought you might wanna read this once - [Using React's Proxy to get ahead of CORS & use HTTPS for API calls](https://blog.praveen.science/using-reacts-proxy-to-get-ahead-of-cors/), but yea, sharing your backend logs will help too.

Comment: I have followed this link and inserting empty "proxy" key.. now I am having "Error: Request failed with status code 404" in my browser console

Comment: After resolving things as per your suggestion; i am still getting the same proxy error.